# can'i inject a mock object(service) with testng

Tags: spring, testng, mockito

this my stackTrace:

```
ERROR TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@175078b] to prepare test instance [cat.base.pse.ui.CercaPeticionsTest@12d15a9]
```

org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInstantiation(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:243)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:959)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:329)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:255)
        at org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextPrepareTestInstance(AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java:117)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:175)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:107)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:51)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:85)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1197)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1122)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1030)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:217)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:92)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
        as.IPseService]: expected at least 1 matching bean
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:613)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:412)
        ... 35 more
    FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass springTestContextPrepareTestInstance
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cat.base.pse.ui.CercaPeticionsTest': Autowiring of fields failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected cat.base.pse.serveis.IPseService cat.base.pse.ui.CercaPeticionsTest.serveiPSE; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [cat.base.pse.serveis.IPseService] is defined: Unsatisfied dependency of type [interface cat.base.pse.serveis.IPseService]: expected at least 1 matching bean
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInstantiation(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:243)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:959)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:329)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:255)
        at org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextPrepareTestInstance(AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java:117)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:175)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:107)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:51)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:85)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1197)

Comment: No context provided, you should explain your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was the way to call the test-context. 
[image]

so the applicationContext-gui-Test.xml wasn't at root src/test/java/resources so I need to specify absolute path:

old wrong way:
`@ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath*:applicationContext-gui-Test.xml")`

Correcte way: `@ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath:cat/base/pse/ui/applicationContext-gui-Test.xml")`